# How can i make a startmenu in python?

Tags: python, menu, python-3.4, 2d-games, startmenu

i have been trying to add a start menu to a game i have been making and have looked everywhere to see how to make a start menu. I did try to use a tutorial by sentdex but it didn't work for my code! And i have also looked in many other places. Does anyone know how to make a start menu - thanks! Here is my code! (Sorry for the bad indents and spaces and stuff, i found it hard to get it to work on here!

```
from tkinter import * 
import pongtablev2, redball, bat


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

x_velocity = 10
y_velocity = 0
score_left = 0
score_right = 0
score_top = 0
score_bottom = 0
first_serve = True


window = Tk()
window.title("MyPong")


my_pongtablev2 = pongtablev2.Table(window, net_colour="blue",vertical_net=True, horizontal_net=True)


my_redball = redball.Ball(table=my_pongtablev2, x_speed=x_velocity,y_speed=y_velocity,
                          width=24, height=24, colour="green", x_start=288, y_start=290)

bat_L = bat.Bat(table=my_pongtablev2, width=15, height=100, x_posn=20, y_posn=250, colour="red")
bat_R = bat.Bat(table=my_pongtablev2, width=15, height=100, x_posn=575, y_posn=250, colour="red")
bat_T = bat.Bat(table=my_pongtablev2, width=100, height=15, x_posn=250, y_posn=15, colour="red")
bat_B = bat.Bat(table=my_pongtablev2, width=100, height=15, x_posn=250, y_posn=570, colour="red")


def game_flow():
    global first_serve
    global score_left
    global score_right
    global score_top
    global score_bottom


if(first_serve == True):
    my_redball.stop_ball()
    first_serve = False

bat_L.detect_collision(my_redball)
bat_R.detect_collision(my_redball)
bat_T.detect_collision(my_redball)
bat_B.detect_collision(my_redball)


if(my_redball.x_posn <= 3):
    my_redball.stop_ball()
    my_redball.start_position()
    bat_L.start_position()
    bat_R.start_position()
    bat_T.start_position()
    bat_B.start_position
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_L.rectangle, 20, 250, 35, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_R.rectangle, 575, 250, 590, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_T.rectangle, 250, 15, 350, 30)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_B.rectangle, 250, 570, 350, 585) 
    score_left = score_left + 1
    if(score_left >= 10):
        score_left = "WINNER!!!"
        score_right = "Looser"
        score_top = "Looser"
        score_bottom = "Looser"
    first_serve = True
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score(score_left, score_right)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score2(score_top)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score3(score_bottom)

if(my_redball.x_posn + my_redball.width >= my_pongtablev2.width - 3):
    my_redball.stop_ball()
    my_redball.start_position()
    bat_L.start_position()
    bat_R.start_position()
    bat_T.start_position()
    bat_B.start_position()
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_L.rectangle, 20, 250, 35, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_R.rectangle, 575, 250, 590, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_T.rectangle, 250, 15, 350, 30)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_B.rectangle, 250, 570, 350, 585) 
    score_right = score_right + 1
    if(score_right >= 10):
        score_right = "WINNER!!!"
        score_left = "Looser"
        score_top = "Looser"
        score_bottom = "Looser"
    first_serve = True
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score(score_left, score_right)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score2(score_top)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score3(score_bottom)


if(my_redball.y_posn <= 3):
    my_redball.stop_ball()
    my_redball.start_position()
    bat_L.start_position()
    bat_R.start_position()
    bat_T.start_position()
    bat_B.start_position()
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_L.rectangle, 20, 250, 35, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_R.rectangle, 575, 250, 590, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_T.rectangle, 250, 15, 350, 30)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_B.rectangle, 250, 570, 350, 585)
    score_top = score_top + 1
    if(score_top >= 10):
        score_top = "WINNER!!!"
        score_left = "Looser"
        score_right = "Looser"
        score_bottom = "Looser"
    first_serve = True
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score3(score_bottom)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score(score_left, score_right)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score2(score_top)


if(my_redball.y_posn + my_redball.height >= my_pongtablev2.height - 3):
    my_redball.stop_ball()
    my_redball.start_position()
    bat_L.start_position()
    bat_R.start_position()
    bat_T.start_position()
    bat_B.start_position()
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_L.rectangle, 20, 250, 35, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_R.rectangle, 575, 250, 590, 350)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_T.rectangle, 250, 15, 350, 30)
    my_pongtablev2.move_item(bat_B.rectangle, 250, 570, 350, 585) 
    score_bottom = score_bottom + 1
    if(score_bottom >= 10):
        score_bottom = "WINNER!!!"
        score_right = "Looser"
        score_left = "Looser"
        score_top = "Looser"
    first_serve = True
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score2(score_top)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score3(score_bottom)
    my_pongtablev2.draw_score(score_left, score_left)

my_redball.move_next()
window.after(17, game_flow)


def restart_game(master):
global score_left
global score_right
global score_top
global score_bottom
my_redball.start_ball(x_speed=x_velocity, y_speed=11)
if(score_left == "WINNER!!!" or score_right == "Looser" or  score_top == "Looser" or score_bottom == "Looser"):
    score_left = 0
    score_right = 0
    score_top = 0
    score_bottom = 0
my_pongtablev2.draw_score(score_left, score_right,)
my_pongtablev2.draw_score2(score_top)
my_pongtablev2.draw_score3(score_bottom)


 window.bind("q", bat_L.move_up)
 window.bind("a", bat_L.move_down)
 window.bind("<Up>", bat_R.move_up)
 window.bind("<Down>", bat_R.move_down)
 window.bind("u", bat_T.move_left)
 window.bind("i", bat_T.move_right)
 window.bind("n", bat_B.move_left)
 window.bind("m", bat_B.move_right)


window.bind("<space>", restart_game)


game_flow()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please edit your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, i am new to python and i didn't really need to show the code it was just a reference in case you needed it!☺

Comment: As it stands, this question simply dumps a program and asks SO to implement a feature for it. Try to create it yourself first. Then, if you run into a specific problem, post just the code that allows us to see, replicate, and troubleshoot that problem.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try something and if it doesn't work i will come back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by "start menu" you mean what is commonly called a "toplevel menu", "application menu", or "application menu-bar". On MS-Windows, for example, this would be a menu that appears across the top of the application window.

Here is a link to some good help about menus: [The Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm). That site has plenty of other good info about Tkinter accessible from links on that page. Also, [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) is an excellent resource.

But to address your specific question, and using your code, just after these two lines:

```
window = Tk()
window.title("MyPong")
```

First, add these two lines:

```
menu_bar = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menu_bar)
```

This creates the application menu (aka menu-bar). Note that the `config()` function (with the `menu=parameter`) is called on the **Tk object**. This is what makes it an application window. (You can associate menus with other windows and widgets too, and create context menus, etc. all using the same `Tk.Menu` class.)

Then add whatever menus you want to have on this menu-bar by using `Menu.add_cascade()`. For example, a "File" menu is quite common:

```
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
```

And finally, you add the menu commands using `Menu.add_command()` and passing a callable object via the command= parameter:

```
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=create_a_new_game)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_a_saved_game)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_the_game)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=callback)
```

Just use `Menu.add_cascade()` to add other menus. For example, another popular menu is "Help":

```
help_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
help_menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help_menu)
help_menu.add_command(label="About", command=show_help)
```

If you want sub-menus, you can use just use `Menu.add_cascade()` on the menu you added to the menu-bar:

```
file_submenu = Menu(file_menu)
file_menu.add_cascade(label="Submenu", menu=file_submenu)
file_submenu.add_command(label="Something", command=something)
file_submenu.add_command(label="Something Else", command=another)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great explanation and will help me a lot!